# Remember the selected value once refreshed the page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In a page containing a form with select fields, I need to remember the previuos choice (if any) of, for example, the selected state. I want to do it via PHP embedded in JS, where I'm wrong?

```
<script>
<?php
if(isset( $_GET["state"] )){
$selected_state =  $_GET["state"];
?>
$("#state option[<?php echo $selected_state ?>]").attr("selected", "selected");
<?php } ?>
</script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: Use cookies to save/restore the selected state.

Comment: Is your form method="get" ? If it's post you will need to use $_POST instead of $_GET

Comment: I need to remember the "selection" within the dropdown menu. ie if I select Spain in the form, once the page has been refreshed, the select should remember this state.

Comment: Yes, I use GET as method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
$("#state option[<?php echo $selected_state ?>]").attr("selected", "selected");
```

With:

```
$("#state option[value='<?php echo $selected_state ?>']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

---

The problem is with the jQuery selector `#state option[SOMETHING]` which checks if the element `option` has an attribute called `SOMETHING`, where you want to see if the value of an option is equal to `SOMETHING` so we use `#state option[value='SOMETHING']`.

You can find the jQuery selectors docs here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessions in PHP to remember certain data.

For example:

```
session_start();

$foo = 'John';
$_SESSION['user'] = $foo;
// Refresh the browser.
echo $_SESSION['user'];
// Outout: 'John'.
```

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php if you want to learn more.

Be careful of what you store in sessions though, don't store critical data in them.

Comment: Yes, I know about sessions, but I need to remember it within the select dropdown menu. In other word, once refreshed, it should be selected automatically.

Comment: all that would require would be to write a condition check on this page that looks for an active session and if it is set then change the selection to show the corresponding option.
there are other options to save the state like persisting a cookie with the data in it or saving the selection in db table to be called when needed. for something like this i think that sessions are your best bet but its a personal preference.
regardless of what method you choose, you will have to write some logic that will test if theres a value set and place it in the appropriate dropdown if so

Comment: Just check if the session exists, then add an extra option which has the value of the session and define it as selected.